# Assigning data in a to-many relationship

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsset

I'm making an iOS app with different types of quizzes, with all the questions and answer choices stored in `CoreData`.

I created two entities, one called **QuestionData** that has attributes such as 'question' 'answer1' (meaning, answer choice 1), 'answer2' etc, and then another entity called **Quiz**, with attributes like 'name' and 'quizId' and I created a to-many relationship on Quiz called 'dataData' that will refer to all the questions/answers etc.

When I created some test data (to experiment with the relationships), I first created the questionData, then set the name and id for the Quiz, and then I tried to set the data in the relationship like this,

```
[quizInfo setValue:questionData forKey:@"quizData"];
```

Which was supposed to store/set all the questions/answers in the `quizData` key of the Quiz entity. However, I got this unacceptable type error, telling me that it 'desired' an `NSSet`, but i instead gave it a type of `QuestionData`.

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unacceptable type of value for to-many relationship: property = "quizData"; desired type = NSSet; given type = QuestionData; value = <QuestionData: 0x89447a0> (entity: QuestionData; id: 0x8919900 <x-coredata:///QuestionData/t6B583F60-5794-47FA-8A51-
```

I understand the concept of a 'set' however, I'm not sure how I can make `questionData` a set when it comes time to do this

```
[quizInfo setValue:questionData forKey:@"quizData"];
```

Full code:

```
 NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
    QuestionData *questionData = [NSEntityDescription
                                 insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Questiondata"
                                 inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [questionData setValue:@"do you like big basketballs" forKey:@"question"];
    [questionData setValue:@"yes" forKey:@"answer1"];
    [questionData setValue:@"no" forKey:@"answer2"];
    [questionData setValue:@"maybe" forKey:@"answer3"];
    [questionData setValue:@"maybe" forKey:@"correctAnswer"];

    Quiz *quizInfo = [NSEntityDescription
                                  insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Quiz"
                                  inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [quizInfo setValue:@"1" forKey:@"quizId"];
    [quizInfo setValue:@"sportsquiz" forKey:@"name"];
    [quizInfo setValue:questionData forKey:@"quizData"];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap your `questionData` inside a set. Since you only have one question at this time you can use

```
[quizInfo setValue:[NSSet setWithObject:questionData] forKey:@"quizData"];
```

When you have more than one question you can either use:

```
[quizInfo setValue:[NSSet setWithObjects:question1Data,question2Data,question3Data,nil] forKey:@"quizData"];
```

Or you could put your questions into an NSMutableArray and use

```
[quizInfo setValue:[NSSet setWithArray:questionArray] forKey:@"quizData"];
```